# Easy way to get the exact difference between two dates in PHP, including milliseconds

Tags: php, datetime, intervals

I have a need to get the difference between two dates in PHP, down to the millisecond. The dates are both `DateTime` objects (or compatible variants). Since PHP 7.2, `DateTime` stores milliseconds as well.

`DateTime::diff()` returns a `DateInterval` object, however, it doesn't differentiate between different length years or months:

- "20**19**-01-01" — "20**20**-01-01" = 1 year (**365** days)
- "20**20**-01-01" — "20**21**-01-01" = 1 year (**366** days)
- "2019-**01**-01" — "2019-**02**-01" = 1 month (**31** days)
- "2019-**02**-01" — "2019-**03**-01" = 1 month (**28** days)

Is there a nice built-in I haven't found yet that can do this, or will I have to roll my own function?

Comment: _“however, it doesn't differentiate between different length years or months”_ - it’s not supposed to, it uses these “units” as a human would - from the first of one month to the first of the next is considered one month, no matter whether you are dealing with 30, 31 or just 28 days here. If you want something that handles this differently, you’ll need to write it yourself, whether milliseconds are involved or not.

Comment: So what is the output that you want ? give us an example

Comment: @misorude I never said it wasn't supposed to, just that that's not what I want. I would have thought a "scientific" version of `DateTime::diff()` might hav already been written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `DateTime::diff()` to get the `DateInterval`, it will have a [`days`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php#dateinterval.props.days) property that will be set correctly. You can combine this with the `h`, `i`, `s`, and `f` properties to get the correct number of milliseconds.

Comment: If he wants the difference in milliseconds, then that is the perfect answer, but I think he needs the difference *including* the milliseconds.

Comment: Missed "days" right at the bottom with its explanation! I only paid attention to the single letter properties!